# Debugger Unavailable : Debugging is not currently supported when TurboModule is enabled

Tags: react-native

When you access the developer menu `⌘D` to enable Debug session, it says:

> Debugger Unavailable : Debugging is not currently supported when
> TurboModule is enabled

[image]

As of November 2020, there is no documentation mentioning any projected timeline for debugging support when TurboModule is enabled.

Is there any workaround while waiting for an official support to debug javascript in the new React Native architecture?